# How to turn off header installation during boost build?

Tags: boost, b2

Whilst running the b2 install command as well as getting the libs I need built/installed the header files are copied over to the include directory.

While I am iterating on build settings, is it possible to turn off the include copy as it makes the whole process very slow due to the sheer volume of hpp files?

Answer (score 0):

You may enable tagged layout with `--layout=tagged` and set copy destination to boost source folder, b2 would just check those files instead of copying.

So command may look like this:

```
b2 install --layout=tagged --includedir="/path/to/your/boost/source/dir/"
```